# matplotlib - ValueError: weight is invalid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running `python/3.3.2` with `matplotlib/1.5.1`

if I run

```
 x = linspace(0,1,10)
 plot(x,x)
```

I get

```
ValueError: weight is invalid
```

but actually it happens with any matplotlib command. It looks like something in the installation is broken or maybe some configuration. I am looking to some hint on what may be wrong, or maybe how I can override the value of weight to something meaningful. I think it refers to

```
In [1]: matplotlib.rcParams['font.weight']
Out[2]: "['bold']"
```

Comment: What is the value of `matplotlib.rcParams['font.weight']`?

Comment: To fix this more permanently, find and edit your [matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file), and change the value of font.weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `font.weight` `rcParams` should be one of many strings: `'normal'`, `'bold'`, `'bolder'`, etc.

Based on that value you have shown, it's somehow the string-representation of a list containing the string `bold`.

```
str(['bold'])
# "['bold']"
```

You need to change it to simply  `'bold'`.

```
matplotlib.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'bold'
```